# Xcode 5/iOS 7 - localization not working in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, localization, ios-simulator

I was following one of Ray Wenderlich's tutorials on localization but I can't seem to get it working.

I've set my project up for localization in English and French and I have a locaziable.strings file for each:

[image]

The French file has the correct (well as far as Google translate goes) French versions of my string:

[image]

I'm setting the strings by calling the correct key from the localizable.strings file:

```
 NSString* strTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Title", Nil)];
```

And I have the simulator set to French (BTW: Whenever I do a language change the simulator crashes).

But it is not pulling from the correct localizable.strings file. It's still displaying in English:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe you have run the app at some time where the file `Localizable.strings` already existed but has not been localized yet. If this is the case, this unlocalized file still resides in the resources folder in the application bundle in the simulator (when you build an run a new version of your app in the simulator or in the device, unused files will not be deleted). This can lead to problems.

Try to delete the app completely from the simulator and build an run again.

Comment: Brilliant! I shall now commence with my weekend. Thanks!

Comment: When deleting the app, use "Clean" in the "Product" menu of xCode. This is what finally worked for me.

Comment: Uninstalling and cleaning did the trick for me - iOS 8.4, Xcode 6.4 (6E35b)

Answer (score 48):

If you are using xcode 6.1.1 and iOS sdk 8.1,try this workaround.

It seems localization does not work with xCode 6.1 and 8.1 simulator.
Workaround:
Go to "edit schemes" >> "Run" (side bar) >> "Options" tab >> "Application Language"
Select the language you wish to run the app on the simulator.
I got this workaround from [Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504304/ios-8-1-simulator-localization-broken-nslocalizedstring) by [natanavra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126392/natanavra)
 Thanks to him.

However I read on developer [forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1079945#1079945),that it is working in 6.2 beta version of Xcode. Hope it do.

Comment: Perfect, this did it for me!

Comment: In addition you can duplicate the current scheme and have multiple schemes, one for each language you want to test.

Answer (score 13):

I have experienced similar issues (IB localization in my case) on device. So general answer would be

**Device** - Uninstall app and clean project by Shift+CMD+K

**Simulator** - Go iOS simulator > Reset Content and Settings and clean project by Shift+CMD+K

These problems are really annoying. Along with poor ability to update localized strings is localization one of the biggest drawback of iOS development.

Comment: Hey, what do have against pigs :(

Comment: Resetting the device did nothing for me, which I found odd. But cleaning the project did the trick!

Answer (score 11):

Another problem that could cause localization not work is the encoding of the strings file. Localizable.strings's encoding must be UTF-16. The default encoding of text file in xcode is UTF-8, that cause me spending a whole day to check why the localization not work.

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted (I just up-voted it). I have used the same localized.strings file since iOS 2.5, but with iOS 7 it stopped working. I just changed the from UTF-8 to UTF-16 and it is now working - thanks!

Comment: I've opened the file with TextWrangled and the localization stopped working. It changed the encoding...

Comment: You can change the encoding as you wish in textwrangler, just at the bottom border, there's a dropdown list control, select UTF-16 and save the file.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 6.0 and later, Localization not work by changing language in Simulator not working.

You have to edit scheme before running your application.

Go to Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options, change language here.

Now, Run Your Application. It will Work.

For more details, check this answer : [Changing language on iOS 8.1 simulator does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588105/changing-language-on-ios-8-1-simulator-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

My problem for this was an incorrectly encoded character in the localization file.