# multi-language feature not working

Tags: ios8, xcode6

Hi, i Can't access the multi language feature in my application when i try to achieve it through xcode 6 beta in simulator, as i don't have device

I have followed the instructions in http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

But I can't get the output, when i change the language in settings as spanish it keep on showing english text

So i downloaded the original application from the link and run but again the spanish language not appears it show only the English language in ios 8 simulator

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: There are several duplicates of this question in stack overflow. It's a bug in the simulator, and the workaround is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26693892/61569