# iOS 8.1 Simulator Localization broken (NSLocalizedString)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, nslocalizedstring, xcode6.1

**TL;DR:**
**It seems localization does not work with xCode 6.1 and 8.1 simulator.**
Workaround:
Go to "edit schemes" >> "Run" (side bar) >> "Options" tab >> "Application Language"
Select the language you wish to run the app on the simulator.

---

Long Story:

I've updated xCode to 6.1. The update deleted the iOS 7.x simulators and left me only with 8.x simulator.
I've done the following steps:

- I've installed the 7.x simulator
- Cleaned the project
- Deleted the app from the simulators
- Deleted the derived folder for my project

The project supports English and Japanese.
on 7.1 simulator (5s) the localization works as expected.
on 8.1 simulator (5s) it does not work.

I'm guessing Apple broke something with the simulator, because it works on real devices.

Any input on this one, anyone else experienced similar problems?

---

**EDIT**
It seems like a bug in the simulator, reference:
[Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1063365#1063365)

Comment: Had the same issue using GM2 which should be the same which is in store now

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard)

Comment: Please find the working solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26690370/2066428

Comment: Additionally, localization does SOMETIMES neither work on a device: In my case, apps on a device sometimes use the 1st preferred language chosen in the device's settings, and sometimes the base localization.

Comment: Problem still there even iOS 8.1.1/Xcode 6.1.1 is shipped out.

Comment: The workaround of selecting the application language in the Scheme doesn't work for me... Any advice?

Comment: Orion, are you sure you set the language and not the region? There are two options there... And it works for me so far.

Comment: Setting the Language in the build scheme works for me.  For good measure I also set the Language in the simulator.

Comment: Joe, it's basically there so you don't have to change the language in the simulator every time you want to do localization testing.

Comment: In my app, I have two files localized for each language: Localizable.strings and Main.storyboard (for storyboard strings). If I set the language in the build scheme, only Localizable.strings strings are translated to the selected language but not storyboard strings. Anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: @ljmelgui: I had similar problem like yours, and the cause is my Main.storyboard was totally messed up when I export and import xliff. Hope it helps.

Comment: Radar ID 18719505 BTW

Comment: Apple fixed the bug with xCode Version 6.2

Answer (score 11):

This is mentioned in the Xcode 6.1 Release Notes and in other stack overthrow threads, like:

[iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-beta1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-ke)

Comment: Hi Jeremy, the question you're referring to is a bit different and besides the title of the question does not suggest the localization does not work.

Comment: It is the same issue.  Global preferences (including locale and keyboard settings) are not finctioning correctly in the iOS 8.1 simulator.

Comment: You are correct, the hardware keyboards fail as well.