# NSLocale preferredLanguages objectAtIndex:0 always return "en"

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, region, nslocale, ios8.1

Simulator's language already changed to Japanese, why `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]` **always** return `"en"`?

Neither preferred language nor region is related to "en", where does `"en"` come from?

[image: Here is screenshot]

Tried to get `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:`**2**`]`, then crash shows `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (1)`

Does it means there is no any languages are set in simulator? So weird!

This never happened before upgrading to Xcode 6.1 with iOS8.1/7.1.

Meanwhile, tried same thing on my iPhone 5, console output correct thing.

Why so weird? Does anybody have such problems?

### Updates: 1

- Delete Xcode as well as simulators, and reinstall it by downloading from Mac Store.
- Create a new simple project, change simlulator's language
- Still get always "en".

Oh! What's wrong....

---

### Updates: 2

- Today, reinstalled brand new Yosemite by reformatting HD
- Download Xcode 6.1
- Start a new simple default project
- Put these codes
- Change / Add language of simulator, Japanese, Dutch, English,
- Run
- Oh, God! Got only `"en"` again, Japanese and English not found!

## Why still only one `"en"` could be found? Where are Japanese and English?

## What happened to simulators?

## Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Try setting your preferred languages for OS X (not in settings in the simulator?)

Comment: Does preferred language for OS X impact that of iPhone simulator? I don't think so. Anyway, tried but not work.

Comment: [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] is working fine for me on iPhone6 & iPhone6 plus both simulators.

Comment: @Shoaib What's version of Xcode you're using?

Comment: @Shoaib 6.0.1 or 6.1?

Comment: Ver 6.0.1 but i don't think version will matter for this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a bug. It was driving me crazy.
Apple already knows it.

See this answers:

[iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard)

and this:

[iOS 8.1 Simulator Localization broken (NSLocalizedString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504304/ios-8-1-simulator-localization-broken-nslocalizedstring)

(In the answer there is a temporary fix changing the schema)

Best,
gigi

Comment: Exactly. After spending my whole day on installing/uninstalling/reinstall Xcode 5.1.1, 6.0.1, eventually found out `NSLocale` not work correctly was because of Xcode 6.1.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately we have to wait Apple, or use the schema fix.

Comment: PS: you should close the question:) @s1u

Comment: @s1u you have to accept the best answer clicking on the check on left. This way people will immediately know what to read to have a solution or best explanation to the issue. Furthermore the question will not appear in unswared question. This will keep stackoverflow tidy and efficient

Answer (score 1):

My iOS simulator suddenly started reporting `"en"` rather than `"en-US"`, so it seems this issue is still active.

Reproduced in:

- Xcode 8.2.1, iOS 10
- Xcode 9.4.1, iOS 11

I went into the language settings and English and United States were selected. I selected Canada and French, and got `"fr-CA"`. I then switched it back and started getting `"en-US"` again. I've been unable to reproduce the `"en"` issue since.

So it appears we cannot pass the values of `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` on assuming they will be Language-Region pairs.

Comment: Take a look at Settings --> General --> Language & Region --> iPhone Language, in an iOS Simulator. You will find that the Simulator is by default set to "English", not to "English (US)". That is the reason why `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` reports "en" as the system language. The strangest thing is that plain "English" (without a country) seems not to be available on real devices, just on the Simulator.