# Xcode 6 - Localization does not work correctly, always english

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I want to add some languages to my application. At the beginning, I started just in german. So after I finished the application, I wanted to add english to it.
So I opened up the project file, and saw that my applications "Development Language" is english. So I added german there and added german in my `Localizable.strings` file and started to change the english file.
After I was finished, I saw that in my `info.plist` the key `Localization native development region` was set to "en". So I changed it to "de". Unfortunately, the "Development Language" was still "english". So I opened up the `.xcodeproj` file with a text editor and changed the "Development Language" to german. Now my "Development Language" is set correctly to german.

"Use Base Localization" was checked by default.

But now I have the problem, when I run my application with a german device, the whole app is in english and not german. When I run the app with an english device, it's in english,too.

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like it's a Xcode/iOS simulator bug... It works when I follow the instructions on the top of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504304/ios-8-1-simulator-localization-broken-nslocalizedstring) question.