# Objective-C: my Localizable.strings doesn't work

Tags: ios, localization

I try to localise my program. But it isn't going well..
I have Localizable.strings:

```
"News" = "Новости";
```

And my custom Tab Bar class where I put

```
[tabBarItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"News", nil)];
```

And it doesn't work. "News" that all I see on the tab. I try to clear cache but it didn't help. Ok, I checked Localisable file is added to the target, I added `NSLog(@"MY NEWS TAG: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"News", nil))` line to my code. It just prints "News".
Then I added `NSLog(@"localeIdentifier: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);` and it prints localeIdentifier: en_US!!! But iOS Simulator UI has different language. Looks like I get wrong localeIdentifier! Why so?

Comment: And if you change the code to `[tabBarItem setTitle:@"Bobby"]` what is the result?

Comment: Tab with "Bobby". Looks like it totally ignor my Localizable.strings. And I tried to do it in another places not only Tab Bar title - situation is same.

Comment: Localisable file is added to the target? Are there multiple localisable files?

Comment: Yes, looks like added https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1338320/Localizable.png Only one file - Localizable.strings I'm desperate (((

Comment: I added NSLog(@"MY NEWS TAG: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"News", nil)); line to my code. It prints "News".

Comment: I added line NSLog(@"localeIdentifier: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]); It prints localeIdentifier: en_US. But iOS Simulator UI on another language. Looks like I get wrong localisation. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found here: [XCode 5/iOS 7 - localization not working in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058499/xcode-5-ios-7-localization-not-working-in-simulator)

> If you are using xcode 6.1.1 and iOS sdk 8.1,try this workaround.
>
> It seems localization does not work with xCode 6.1 and 8.1 simulator.
>   Workaround: Go to "edit schemes" >> "Run" (side bar) >> "Options" tab
>
> > > "Application Language" Select the language you wish to run the app on the simulator. I got this workaround from Workaround by natanavra
> > >       Thanks to him.
>
> However I read on developer forum,that it is working in 6.2 beta
>   version of Xcode. Hope it do.

Damn! It looks so!