# iOS App Development - Localization Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, localizable.strings

I am trying to Localize my app...

I have set the following in ViewController.m

```
//Lets Play Button
CGRect Play = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-100, self.view.frame.size.height-280, 200, 60);
HTPressableButton *start = [[HTPressableButton alloc] initWithFrame:Play buttonStyle:HTPressableButtonStyleRounded];
start.buttonColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236/255.0f green:101/255.0f blue:128/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
start.shadowHeight = 0;
start.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Intro" size:25];
[start setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LetsPlay", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[start addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[newMain addSubview:start];
```

and set the following in Localizable.strings (This is the Spanish Version)

```
"LetsPlay"="Beunos Noches!";
"Menu"="Adios!";
```

But the button is showing the text as 'LetsPlay'

So it is as if the `NSLocalizedString(@"LetsPlay")` commmand is not working...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you run your project in a Spanish language iOS? Because,I checked what you post,it just runs well on my Mac

Comment: Yeah I went into settings on the Simulator and changed it to spanish ? Unless there is another way ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was working but the simulator has a few teething problems with Localization.

Found the answer here - [XCode 5/iOS 7 - localization not working in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058499/xcode-5-ios-7-localization-not-working-in-simulator)